# $lookup localField reference to specific index in array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, lookup

I have a collection of rankings. Each ranking has an array of 3-tuples (lists) `[rank, user_id, score]`. A single document may look like this:

```
{
    "_id" : 33691,
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-03-03T01:29:31.663Z"),
    "ranks" : [ 
        [1, 53982363, 13666235],
        [2, 26204263, 5544911],
    ]
}
```

Now I want a view on the ranks with full user-data instead of just the user ids, basically a join with my `users` collection. My query looks like this:

```
db.getCollection('pokeyen_bet_rankings').aggregate([
    {$match: {_id: 33691}},
    {$unwind: "$ranks"},
    {$lookup: {
        from: "users",
        localField: "ranks.1",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "user"
    }},
    {$unwind: "$user"}
])
```

But unfortunately it doesn't recognize the value for `localField` of `ranks.1` as the 2nd element of the "tuple", but rather the (nonexistant) field `"ranks.1"` apparently, as it doesn't match a user. My workaround is to extract the first element with a projection first like this (after the `$unwind`):

```
{$project: {
    user_id: {$arrayElemAt: ["$ranks", 1]}
}},
```

and then use that as the `localField`. But I wondered if there is a more straightforward solution to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/),

> If your localField is an array, you’ll need to add an $unwind
>   stage to your pipeline.

So what you did is the correct recommended approach.

Comment: I believe the documentation refers to arrays of IDs like described [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-22881), not tuple-like arrays. In that sense I do have the required `$unwind` stage

Comment: You do have required `$unwind` stage but you don't have the matching structure after that `$unwind` which should be local field or array of local field ids . Its array of IDs as you mentioned in jira ticket, but those are not `UserIds`. Other thing the `localField: <field from the input documents>` only takes field names , so you cant pass the computed property or expression.